# How to handle the delay in ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, firebase

I am working with FireBase, a NOSQL cloud data storage. It can automatically update my JavaScript when the child(data) has been changed. However, i have problem about it.

The script of the ajax:

```
  var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://App_Name.firebaseio.com/session');
        myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
        var message = snapshot.val();
        console.log("out of ajax: user"+ message.userId );
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "showProfile.php",
            data: {userId : message.userId},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) { 
                        console.log("inside ajax: user" + data.userId );
                    },
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
      });
```

The problem one, it is not running Synchronous. Second, it is out of order. The order of `inside ajax:` is just depending on the order which one come first.

the result in console:

```
out of ajax: user1
out of ajax: user2
out of ajax: user3
out of ajax: user4
inside ajax: user3
inside ajax: user2
inside ajax: user4
inside ajax: user1
```

However, my expected result is:

```
out of ajax: user1
inside ajax: user1
out of ajax: user2
inside ajax: user2
out of ajax: user3
inside ajax: user3
out of ajax: user4
inside ajax: user4
```

or

```
out of ajax: user1
out of ajax: user2
out of ajax: user3
out of ajax: user4
inside ajax: user1
inside ajax: user2
inside ajax: user3
inside ajax: user4
```

Comment: you can supply `async: false` to `$.ajax` to make the requests synchronous

Comment: why do you want it to be synchronous by the way?

Comment: @mani I got another bigger problem from it... It will become more more more slower..btw, it wrok synchronous .

Comment: @JF-Mechs if it is in order, fine. But it is not

Comment: @kingyau that's the way JavaScript works. If you need specific order, DO NOT do synchronous stuff: instead, just collect the data and then process it in some other order.

Comment: I just don't get it, why use ajax if you will also make your stuff run  synchronously.. one of the main purpose or benefits of ajax is, it allows you to make asynchronous calls to a server. This is to avoid/lessen waiting time for all data to arrive.

Comment: @JF-Mechs i just want to make that the result is in sequence of the my firebase data. However, it is not. It  just depending on the order which one come first.

Answer (score 0):

I would try Promise if you are in ECMascript 6 browsers. if not, jquery's deferred method also allows you to chain the ajax calls. Here is a good article to start with [An introduction to jQuery Deferred / Promise and the design pattern in general](http://www.danieldemmel.me/blog/2013/03/22/an-introduction-to-jquery-deferred-slash-promise/) . You can find many others online as well.